# model.load_weights() does not load the weights I stored previously using model.save_weights()

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I aim to save and then load the weights of my model using [`save_weights` and `load_weights` functions](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/save_and_load?hl=en#manually_save_weights).

In order to show you a minimal reproducible example, these are the dependencies you can use in my whole example:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.initializers import he_uniform
from keras.layers import Conv2DTranspose, BatchNormalization, Reshape, Dense, Conv2D, Flatten
from keras.optimizers.legacy import Adam
from keras.src.datasets import mnist
from skimage.transform import resize
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator
from tensorflow import keras
```

This is my model, a (variational) autoencoder:

```
class VAE(keras.Model, BaseEstimator):
    def __init__(self, encoder, decoder, epochs=None, l_rate=None, batch_size=None, patience=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.encoder = encoder
        self.decoder = decoder
        self.epochs = epochs  
        self.l_rate = l_rate  
        self.batch_size = batch_size  
        self.patience = patience 
        self.total_loss_tracker = keras.metrics.Mean(name="total_loss")
        self.reconstruction_loss_tracker = keras.metrics.Mean(name="reconstruction_loss")
        self.kl_loss_tracker = keras.metrics.Mean(name="kl_loss")

    def call(self, inputs, training=None, mask=None):
        _, _, z = self.encoder(inputs)
        outputs = self.decoder(z)
        return outputs

    @property
    def metrics(self):
        return [
            self.total_loss_tracker,
            self.reconstruction_loss_tracker,
            self.kl_loss_tracker,
        ]

    def train_step(self, data):
        data, labels = data
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            # Forward pass
            z_mean, z_log_var, z = self.encoder(data)
            reconstruction = self.decoder(z)

            # Compute losses
            reconstruction_loss = tf.reduce_mean(
                tf.reduce_sum(
                    keras.losses.binary_crossentropy(data, reconstruction), axis=(1, 2)
                )
            )
            kl_loss = -0.5 * (1 + z_log_var - tf.square(z_mean) - tf.exp(z_log_var))
            kl_loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.reduce_sum(kl_loss, axis=1))
            total_loss = reconstruction_loss + kl_loss

        # Compute gradient
        grads = tape.gradient(total_loss, self.trainable_weights)

        # Update weights
        self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, self.trainable_weights))

        # Update metrics
        self.total_loss_tracker.update_state(total_loss)
        self.reconstruction_loss_tracker.update_state(reconstruction_loss)
        self.kl_loss_tracker.update_state(kl_loss)

        return {
            "loss": self.total_loss_tracker.result(),
            "reconstruction_loss": self.reconstruction_loss_tracker.result(),
            "kl_loss": self.kl_loss_tracker.result(),
        }

    def test_step(self, data):
        data, labels = data
        # Forward pass
        z_mean, z_log_var, z = self.encoder(data)
        reconstruction = self.decoder(z)

        # Compute losses
        reconstruction_loss = tf.reduce_mean(
            tf.reduce_sum(
                keras.losses.binary_crossentropy(data, reconstruction), axis=(1, 2)
            )
        )
        kl_loss = -0.5 * (1 + z_log_var - tf.square(z_mean) - tf.exp(z_log_var))
        kl_loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.reduce_sum(kl_loss, axis=1))
        total_loss = reconstruction_loss + kl_loss

        # Update metrics
        self.total_loss_tracker.update_state(total_loss)
        self.reconstruction_loss_tracker.update_state(reconstruction_loss)
        self.kl_loss_tracker.update_state(kl_loss)

        return {
            "loss": self.total_loss_tracker.result(),
            "reconstruction_loss": self.reconstruction_loss_tracker.result(),
            "kl_loss": self.kl_loss_tracker.result(),
        }
```

This is the Encoder:

```
@keras.saving.register_keras_serializable()
class Encoder(keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, latent_dimension):
        super(Encoder, self).__init__()
        self.latent_dim = latent_dimension

        seed = 42

        self.conv1 = Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation="relu", strides=2, padding="same",
                            kernel_initializer=he_uniform(seed))
        self.bn1 = BatchNormalization()

        self.conv2 = Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=3, activation="relu", strides=2, padding="same",
                            kernel_initializer=he_uniform(seed))
        self.bn2 = BatchNormalization()

        self.conv3 = Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=3, activation="relu", strides=2, padding="same",
                            kernel_initializer=he_uniform(seed))
        self.bn3 = BatchNormalization()

        self.flatten = Flatten()
        self.dense = Dense(units=100, activation="relu")

        self.z_mean = Dense(latent_dimension, name="z_mean")
        self.z_log_var = Dense(latent_dimension, name="z_log_var")

        self.sampling = sample

    def call(self, inputs, training=None, mask=None):
        x = self.conv1(inputs)
        x = self.bn1(x)
        x = self.conv2(x)
        x = self.bn2(x)
        x = self.conv3(x)
        x = self.bn3(x)
        x = self.flatten(x)
        x = self.dense(x)
        z_mean = self.z_mean(x)
        z_log_var = self.z_log_var(x)
        z = self.sampling(z_mean, z_log_var)
        return z_mean, z_log_var, z
```

Where `sample` function is defined below:

```
def sample(z_mean, z_log_var):
    batch = tf.shape(z_mean)[0]
    dim = tf.shape(z_mean)[1]
    epsilon = tf.random.normal(shape=(batch, dim))
    stddev = tf.exp(0.5 * z_log_var)
    return z_mean + stddev * epsilon
```

And finally this is the Decoder:

```
@keras.saving.register_keras_serializable()
class Decoder(keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Decoder, self).__init__()
        self.dense1 = Dense(units=4096, activation="relu")
        self.bn1 = BatchNormalization()

        self.dense2 = Dense(units=1024, activation="relu")
        self.bn2 = BatchNormalization()

        self.dense3 = Dense(units=4096, activation="relu")
        self.bn3 = BatchNormalization()

        seed = 42

        self.reshape = Reshape((4, 4, 256))
        self.deconv1 = Conv2DTranspose(filters=256, kernel_size=3, activation="relu", strides=2, padding="same",
                                       kernel_initializer=he_uniform(seed))
        self.bn4 = BatchNormalization()

        self.deconv2 = Conv2DTranspose(filters=128, kernel_size=3, activation="relu", strides=1, padding="same",
                                       kernel_initializer=he_uniform(seed))
        self.bn5 = BatchNormalization()

        self.deconv3 = Conv2DTranspose(filters=128, kernel_size=3, activation="relu", strides=2, padding="valid",
                                       kernel_initializer=he_uniform(seed))
        self.bn6 = BatchNormalization()

        self.deconv4 = Conv2DTranspose(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation="relu", strides=1, padding="valid",
                                       kernel_initializer=he_uniform(seed))
        self.bn7 = BatchNormalization()

        self.deconv5 = Conv2DTranspose(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation="relu", strides=2, padding="valid",
                                       kernel_initializer=he_uniform(seed))
        self.bn8 = BatchNormalization()

        self.deconv6 = Conv2DTranspose(filters=1, kernel_size=2, activation="sigmoid", padding="valid",
                                       kernel_initializer=he_uniform(seed))

    def call(self, inputs, training=None, mask=None):
        x = self.dense1(inputs)
        x = self.bn1(x)
        x = self.dense2(x)
        x = self.bn2(x)
        x = self.dense3(x)
        x = self.bn3(x)
        x = self.reshape(x)
        x = self.deconv1(x)
        x = self.bn4(x)
        x = self.deconv2(x)
        x = self.bn5(x)
        x = self.deconv3(x)
        x = self.bn6(x)
        x = self.deconv4(x)
        x = self.bn7(x)
        x = self.deconv5(x)
        x = self.bn8(x)
        decoder_outputs = self.deconv6(x)
        return decoder_outputs
```

This is the `main` code:

```
def normalize(x):
    return (x - np.min(x)) / (np.max(x) - np.min(x))
    
def create_vae():
    latent_dimension = 25
    best_epochs = 2500
    best_l_rate = 10 ** -5
    best_batch_size = 32
    best_patience = 30

    encoder = Encoder(latent_dimension)
    decoder = Decoder()
    vae = VAE(encoder, decoder, best_epochs, best_l_rate, best_batch_size, best_patience)
    vae.compile(Adam(best_l_rate))
    return vae

if __name__ == '__main__':
    (x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
    new_shape = (40, 40)  # VAE deals with (None, 40, 40, 1) tensors
    x_train = np.array([resize(img, new_shape) for img in x_train])
    x_test = np.array([resize(img, new_shape) for img in x_test])
    x_train = np.expand_dims(x_train, axis=-1).astype("float32")
    x_test = np.expand_dims(x_test, axis=-1).astype("float32")

    x_train = normalize(x_train)
    x_test = normalize(x_test)

    # Let's consider the first 100 items only for speed purposes
    x_train = x_train[:100]
    y_train = y_train[:100]
    x_test = x_test[:100]
    y_test = y_test[:100]
    
    model = create_vae()
    model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=64, epochs=10)
    weights_before_load = model.get_weights()
    model.save_weights("test-checkpoints/my-vae")

    del model

    model = create_vae()
    model.load_weights("test-checkpoints/my-vae")
    weights_after_load = model.get_weights()

    for layer_num, (w_before, w_after) in enumerate(zip(weights_before_load, weights_after_load), start=1):
        print(f"Layer {layer_num}:")
        print(f"Same weights? {w_before.all() == w_after.all()}")
```

And this is the output:

```
Layer 1:
Same weights? True

Layer 2:
Same weights? False  # WHY FALSE HERE?

Layer 3:
Same weights? True

Layer 4:
Same weights? True

Layer 5:
Same weights? True

Layer 6:
Same weights? True
```

But I expected the weights to be the same before and after the load! Why aren't the weights in the Layer 2 the same after I loaded them using `load_weights` method?

Furthermore this is a list of warnings I get:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Detecting that an object or model or tf.train.Checkpoint is being deleted with unrestored values. See the following logs for the specific values in question. To silence these warnings, use `status.expect_partial()`. See https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Checkpoint#restorefor details about the status object returned by the restore function.
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).optimizer.iter
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).optimizer.beta_1
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).optimizer.beta_2
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).optimizer.decay
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).optimizer.learning_rate
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).encoder.conv1.kernel
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).encoder.conv1.bias
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).encoder.bn1.gamma
...
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).encoder.conv3.bias
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).encoder.bn3.gamma
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).encoder.bn3.beta
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).encoder.bn3.moving_mean
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).encoder.bn3.moving_variance
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).encoder.dense.kernel
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).encoder.dense.bias
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).encoder.z_mean.kernel
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).encoder.z_mean.bias
...
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).decoder.bn2.moving_variance
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).decoder.dense3.kernel
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).decoder.dense3.bias
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).decoder.bn3.gamma
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).decoder.bn3.beta
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).decoder.bn3.moving_mean
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).decoder.bn3.moving_variance
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).decoder.deconv1.kernel
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).decoder.deconv1.bias
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).decoder.bn4.gamma
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).decoder.bn4.beta
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).decoder.bn4.moving_mean
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).decoder.bn4.moving_variance
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).decoder.deconv2.kernel
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).decoder.deconv2.bias
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).decoder.bn5.gamma
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).decoder.bn5.beta
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).decoder.bn5.moving_mean
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).decoder.bn5.moving_variance
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).decoder.deconv3.kernel
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).decoder.deconv3.bias
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).decoder.bn6.gamma
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).decoder.bn6.beta
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).decoder.bn6.moving_mean
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).decoder.bn6.moving_variance
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).decoder.deconv4.kernel
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).decoder.deconv4.bias
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).decoder.bn7.gamma
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).decoder.bn7.beta
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).decoder.bn7.moving_mean
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).decoder.bn7.moving_variance
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).decoder.deconv5.kernel
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).decoder.deconv5.bias
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).decoder.bn8.gamma
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).decoder.bn8.beta
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).decoder.bn8.moving_mean
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).decoder.bn8.moving_variance
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).decoder.deconv6.kernel
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).decoder.deconv6.bias
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).optimizer's state 'm' for (root).encoder.conv1.kernel
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).optimizer's state 'm' for (root).encoder.conv1.bias
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).optimizer's state 'm' for (root).encoder.bn1.gamma
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).optimizer's state 'm' for (root).encoder.bn1.beta
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).optimizer's state 'm' for (root).encoder.conv2.kernel
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).optimizer's state 'm' for (root).encoder.conv2.bias
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).optimizer's state 'm' for (root).encoder.bn2.gamma
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).optimizer's state 'm' for (root).encoder.bn2.beta
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).optimizer's state 'm' for (root).encoder.conv3.kernel
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).optimizer's state 'm' for (root).encoder.conv3.bias
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).optimizer's state 'm' for (root).encoder.bn3.gamma
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).optimizer's state 'm' for (root).encoder.bn3.beta
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).optimizer's state 'm' for (root).encoder.dense.kernel
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).optimizer's state 'm' for (root).encoder.dense.bias
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).optimizer's state 'm' for (root).encoder.z_mean.kernel
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).optimizer's state 'm' for (root).encoder.z_mean.bias
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).optimizer's state 'm' for (root).encoder.z_log_var.kernel
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).optimizer's state 'm' for (root).encoder.z_log_var.bias
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).optimizer's state 'm' for (root).decoder.dense1.kernel
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).optimizer's state 'm' for (root).decoder.dense1.bias
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).optimizer's state 'm' for (root).decoder.bn1.gamma
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).optimizer's state 'm' for (root).decoder.bn1.beta
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).optimizer's state 'm' for (root).decoder.dense2.kernel
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).optimizer's state 'm' for (root).decoder.dense2.bias
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).optimizer's state 'm' for (root).decoder.bn2.gamma
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).optimizer's state 'm' for (root).decoder.bn2.beta
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).optimizer's state 'm' for (root).decoder.dense3.kernel
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).optimizer's state 'm' for (root).decoder.dense3.bias
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).optimizer's state 'm' for (root).decoder.bn3.gamma
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).optimizer's state 'm' for (root).decoder.bn3.beta
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).optimizer's state 'm' for (root).decoder.deconv1.kernel
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).optimizer's state 'm' for (root).decoder.deconv1.bias
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).optimizer's state 'm' for (root).decoder.bn4.gamma
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).optimizer's state 'm' for (root).decoder.bn4.beta
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).optimizer's state 'm' for (root).decoder.deconv2.kernel
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).optimizer's state 'm' for (root).decoder.deconv2.bias
...
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).optimizer's state 'v' for (root).decoder.deconv6.kernel
WARNING:tensorflow:Value in checkpoint could not be found in the restored object: (root).optimizer's state 'v' for (root).decoder.deconv6.bias

Process finished with exit code 0
```

How do I fix the issue?

Note that I truncated the warnings output because of their size.

This is weird since if I re-run my example on another model as you can see here:

```
def create_model():
    model = tf.keras.Sequential([
        keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu', input_shape=(784,)),
        keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
        keras.layers.Dense(10)
    ])

    model.compile(optimizer=Adam(),
                  loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
                  metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()])

    return model

if __name__ == '__main__':
    (x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
    y_train = y_train[:100]
    y_test = y_test[:100]
    x_train = x_train[:100].reshape(-1, 28 * 28) / 255.0
    x_test = x_test[:100].reshape(-1, 28 * 28) / 255.0

    model = create_model()
    model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=32, epochs=10)

    model.save_weights("test-checkpoints/my-model")
    weights_before = model.get_weights()

    del model

    model = create_model()
    model.load_weights("test-checkpoints/my-model")
    weights_after = model.get_weights()

    for layer_num, (w_before, w_after) in enumerate(zip(weights_before, weights_after), start=1):
        print(f"Layer {layer_num}:")
        print(f"Same weights? {w_before.all() == w_after.all()}")
```

then you can notice that `model.save_weights()` and `model.load_weights()` worked properly, since weights are all the same:

```
Layer 1:
Same weights? True


Layer 2:
Same weights? True


Layer 3:
Same weights? True


Layer 4:
Same weights? True
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before loading weights I had to train the model on a batch like this:

```
vae.train_on_batch(x_train[:1], x_train[:1])
```